# Extreme points of a convex set

Tags: convex-geometry, convexity

Let $S$ denote the set of all complex non-negative definite matrices with all diagonal elements being less that or equal to one. Can we show that any matrix which belongs to the set of all non-zero extreme points of $S$ has all its diagonal elements equal to zero or one?

Comment: Non-negative definite = hermitian with some eigenvalues positive? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Igor. Hermitian + all eigenvalues non-negative.

Comment: This cannot be true because the set is the closed convex hull of its extreme points. Or in more elementary style, $0$ is certainly an extreme point.

Comment: What could perhaps be true is that the extreme points have diag entries zero or one.

Comment: @ Christian. Edited.

Comment: I think that, when editing, you copied the suggestion from @ChristianRemling incorrectly. The matrix $\binom{1\ 0}{0\ 0}$ is a non-zero extreme point.

Comment: @ Andreas. Yes. I copied and copied again. What is wrong in that? What he said is correct.

Comment: Standard terminology is "positive semidefinite" (PSD).

Comment: Sorry for ignorance, but what is the "space" here within which this is a convex set? The set of all linear functions from $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^m$ for all $n,m \geq 1$? Or for fixed $n,m$?

Comment: @usul  $m=n.$ hermitian matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The extremal rays of the PSD cone are the rank one matrices (also known as projections),so those of the form $x x^t.$ - see, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678693/positive-semidefinite-cone-is-generated-by-all-rank-one-matrices

The answer to your question follows immediately.

Comment: no, the question is whether on the boundary one always get matrices with only 0 or 1 on the diagonal. E.g. for x=(1,1/2) one gets an extreme matrix which is not like this.

Answer (score 1):

Rank one matrices $xx^\top$ are extreme, now take $x=(1,1/2)$. This gives $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1/2\\1/2&1/4\end{pmatrix}$, a counterexample to your conjecture.

Comment: @ Dima and Igor. I am talking about extreme points of the set of all non-negative definite matrices. I am considering a special convex set of non-negative matrices with diagonal entries all less than or equal to one. So your argument is not correct.

Comment: the matrix I give is in your set, and we claim it is extreme

Comment: @ Dima and Igor. I am really sorry. you are absolutely right.